# Is this a mistake in the book: de Moivre applied to real number is multip valued?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider

$$ z^n = \rho^n (\cos (n \theta) + i \sin (n \theta))$$

for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

It is written in the book I am reading that this is multi-valued when $n$ is replaced by a real number.

> Is this true? And if so: why does it become multivalued?

It seems weird to me because $\theta$ is already real so $n \theta$ is already real so it seems to me that making $n$ real too does not change anything.

Comment: it's true.  If $w$ is complex and $x$ is real but, say, irrational, $w^x$ is multivalued, largely because $\log w$ is multivalued and $w^x = e^{x \log w}$

Comment: "...because $\theta$ is already real".  True we choose $\theta$ as a real number but subject to a choice of adding any integer multiple of $2\pi$.  It is this periodicity of $\theta$ that gets disrupted if $n\not\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @WillJagy I find your comment most helpful among all comments and answer. Please could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's true. If $w$ is complex and $x$ is real but, say, irrational, $w^x$ is multivalued, largely because $\log w$ is multivalued and $w^x=e^{x \log w}$

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that $\theta$ is not uniquely defined, but can vary by multiples of $2\pi$ for the same value of $z$.  This ambiguity is harmless when $n$ is an integer since $n$ times a multiple of $2\pi$ is still a multiple of $2\pi$.  But when $n \notin \mathbb Z$ you do get multiple different values.  If $n$ is irrational, you in fact get *infinitely* many different values.

Answer (score 1):

If $n$ is a real number then $\rho^n$ could have multiple values. For instance when $n=1/2$ you can have the positive and negative square roots of $\rho$.